# deduction guides for matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I'm looking for deduction guide for initialize matrix.

I've tried to use pack in pack and `sizeof...`, `initializer_list<initializer_list<T>>`, custom classes for arrays for construct, but nothing is works...

so, i'm looking for initialize

```
template <class T, size_t s1, size_t s2>
class matrix
{
T matr[s1][s2]; //maybe with custom array class, if this problem need this
public:
//constructor
};
//deductor
```

like

```
matrix m{{1, 2}, {1, 2}};
```

or

```
matrix m({1, 2}, {1, 2});
```

Comment: Issue with `{/*..*/}` is that it doesn't have type (or `intializer_list` which doesn't have compile time size).

Comment: `matrix m{std::array{1, 2}, std::array{1, 2}};` might be possible though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the way to avoid the additional brackets.

This time is required also an explicit deduction guides, SFINAE and an additional method to initialize the `matr` member but should works.

The following is a full complete example

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, std::size_t s1, std::size_t s2>
class matrix
 {
   private:
      T matr[s1][s2];

      void init_row (std::size_t i, T const (&arr)[s2])
       {
         for ( auto j = 0u ; j < s2 ; ++j )
            matr[i][j] = arr[j];
       }

   public:
      template <std::size_t ... Dims,
                std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Dims) == s1, bool> = true,
                std::enable_if_t<((Dims == s2) && ...), bool> = true>
      matrix (T const (&...arrs)[Dims])
       { std::size_t i = -1; (init_row(++i, arrs), ...); }
 };

template <typename T, std::size_t Dim0, std::size_t ... Dims,
          std::enable_if_t<((Dim0 == Dims) && ...), bool> = true>
matrix (T const (&)[Dim0], T const (&...arrs)[Dims])
   -> matrix<T, 1u+sizeof...(Dims), Dim0>;


int main()
{
   matrix m{{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}};

   static_assert( std::is_same_v<decltype(m), matrix<int, 3u, 2u>> );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe... if you can accept to add another level of brackets in variable construction...

```
matrix m{{{1, 2}, {1, 2}}};
// ......^..............^   another level
```

you can construct `matrix` receiving an array of array, so `T`, `s1` and `s2` are automatically deduced

```
template <typename T, std::size_t s1, std::size_t s2>
class matrix
 {
   using ca1 = T const [s1];
   using ca2 = ca1 const [s2];

   T matr[s1][s2];

   public:
   matrix (ca2 & arr2d)
    {
      for ( auto ui = 0u ; ui < s1 ; ++ui )
        for ( auto uj = 0u ; uj < s2 ; ++uj )
           matr[ui][uj] = arr2d[ui][uj];
    }
 };
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, std::size_t s1, std::size_t s2>
class matrix
 {
   using ca1 = T const [s1];
   using ca2 = ca1 const [s2];

   T matr[s1][s2];

   public:
   matrix (ca2 & arr2d)
    {
      for ( auto ui = 0u ; ui < s1 ; ++ui )
        for ( auto uj = 0u ; uj < s2 ; ++uj )
           matr[ui][uj] = arr2d[ui][uj];
    }
 };

int main()
{
   matrix m{{{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}}};
}
```

Comment: have you tried this? What deduction guides are you using? I don't think deduction guides work at all for this syntax.

Comment: @bolov - I've tried and works with g++ and clang++.

Comment: It works: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d6cf4908bb1cad3). CTAD used is the default one, as max66 provides constructor.

Comment: ohh, no explicit deduction guides. I see.

Comment: @bolov - added a full compiling example (but is trivial)

Comment: It's really good idea @max66. Thanks! I gonna use it. But i keep looking for {{}, {}} realization. And i wanna to see the deduction guides in this example

Comment: @naufumi - sorry but I don't see a way to avoid the additional brackets (without an additional `make_matrix()` function); I'm trying another example that uses `std::array` and an explicit deduction guides (not sure can work) but the additional brackets are required also in this case.

Comment: @naufumi - added another answer with a solution with explicit deduction guides and no additional brackets (but is more complicated).